# How to loop a variant until the statement is correct using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. For this moment I am familiar with using macrorecorder and some basic staff.

Unfortunately for this moment I'm not 100% sure how to use loop.
I need to add 1 to a value in cell AH4 (in this formula it's RC[-37]) if the value in cell BR4 = 1.
This procedure must be done till this statement is correct: Range("CG3") < Range("BP2")

Here is what I got for now:

```
Sub 1()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    Do While Range("CG3") < Range("BP2")

        If Range("BR4") = 1 Then
            Range("BS4").FormulaR1C1 = " = RC[-37] +  i"
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Range("BS4").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-37]"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share what's in those various cells (e.g. `CG3`, `BP2`...)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Hi!

CG3 is a Sum of values from CG4 to CG1000 
BP2 is my target value

The thing is, when I change the value in cell BS4, the other one (CG3) gets closer to my target value BP2.
Idea is that I want to add 1 to cell BS4 (and till the last one in column BS) in order to get     CG3 almost equal to BP2.
For e.g. I want CG3 = 79 and BP2 = 80 (or 68 and 70)

Hope I say clear

Comment: `Do While Range("CG3") < Range("BP2")` will either be false at the beginning, or is true forever, since the values of those cells never change in your sub, unless their formulas reference the cell `BS4` that you are modifying.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh, maybe it is one of the things I will change. My biggest concern is adding 1 to the range (i = i + 1). I tried placing this statement here and there but I got nothing. I guess it's the wrong method (FormulaR1C1)

Comment: Ah.. I see a problem: in `Range("BS4").FormulaR1C1 = " = RC[-37] +  i"` the variable `i` is included in the formula, but the sheet will not know that variable. Change to `Range("BS4").FormulaR1C1 = " = RC[-37] +  " & i` to use the _value_ of `i`.